# google chrome error with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, canvas

i'm trying to put the image in the canvas and this happens...

> "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on
>   'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type
>   '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or
>   ImageBitmap)'"

...in Chrome.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("start");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById("kid");
ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>beta</title>
</body>
<link href="chip.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<canvas height="938" width="1890" id="start"></canvas>
<script src="beta.js"></script>
<img src="chio.jpg"id="kid"/>
</html>
```

html and css works fine. JavaScript the problem.

Comment: what's going on with the semicolon in `<img src="chio.jpg";id="kid"/>`?

Comment: The markup is a complete mess... Why the closing `</body>` in the head? And also the already mentioned semicolon in the `<img>` tag. After fixing these it still won't work. You will have to move the `<script>...</script>` **after** the `<img />`. Otherwise `document.getElementById("kid")` will be `null`

Comment: this is hilarious.. just sayin..

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the weird semicolon that you have in the `img` tag.

Replace

```
<img src="chio.jpg";id="kid"/>
```

with

```
<img src="chio.jpg" id="kid"/>
```